# Google Analytics Core Reporting started to return: Responde code: 403. Reason: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile

Tags: google-analytics

I've been using the Google Analytics Core Reporting API (endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga) without issues until recently. Suddenly, I started receiving a 403 error with the message: "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

**Here's what I've observed and tried so far:**

1. No Changes Made: The error occurred without any recent changes in the API request or configuration.
2. APIs Checked: I attempted to use the Management and Admin APIs to diagnose the issue but didn't find any leads.
3. ViewID Missing: In the account summary, the ViewID, which we use for core reporting, is missing. I'm not sure if this is related, as the ViewID corresponds to the profile ID, while the account summary shows the account ID.
4. Attempt to Use API v4: I tried switching to the Google Analytics Reporting API v4, but the error persists.

**Additional Context:**

- I do not have direct access to the Google Analytics account.
- The API was functioning correctly until this sudden error.

```py
url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
headers = {
        'Authorization': token}'
    }

payload = {
            'client_id': x',
            'client_secret': x',
            'refresh_token': x',
            'grant_type': 'x'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

token = f"{response_obj['token_type']} {response_obj['access_token']}"

# Get the auth token and make the request:

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga'

headers = {
        'Authorization': f"{token}"
    }


params = {
        'ids': 'ga:227x',
        'metrics': '{x}', ...
    }


response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

**Question:**
How can I resolve this 403 error, considering I don't have access to the Google account itself? Is the missing ViewID a possible cause, and if so, how can I address this issue?

Comment: Have you checked Google analytics are they starting shutting accounts down now. Does your profile still exist.   If you dont have direct access to the google analytics account how did you use the api?  Can we see your code.

Comment: I access using the client_id, client_secret and the tokens to authenticate. So, I tried to check if my profile still exists, but I couldn't verify it through the api (management, admin).

I updated the question to show snippet of the code

Comment: Client I'd and client secret still require a user to consent to give you an access token and refresh token. Who ever gave you that refresh token may have lost access to the profile or the profile was deleted

Comment: Actually, it has never requested the consent. We just make a request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token and it returns the access_token.

The refresh token we already have

Comment: Yes but where did you get the refresh token